# How to differentiate an implementation from specification

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, specifications

Assume that I have a simple servlet program which requires only the web container. Also assume that I am not using an IDE to compile this program. I can compile my program as follows.

```
javac -classpath /path/tomcat/common/lib/servlet-api.jar -d classes src/Ch1Servlet.java
```

I have been said by some people that `servlet-api.jar` just contains the specification, and the implementation is provided by the tomcat server. This confuses me.

If I compiled a program using a library, I still need the same library when I am running the program also. Therefore at some point Tomcat has to use the same library specified above (servlet-api.jar) when running the application.

What is really meant by implementation and specification? What makes a code just a specification? An example in code would be really helpful.

Comment: (English)Specification:Implementation :: (Java)Interface:Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces/Abstract classes contribute to a spec and the actual implementation of it is what is used by us as the implementation.

Comment: you mean there cannot be any classes in a specification?

Comment: You can have Abstract classes.

Comment: abstract classes with non-abstract methods?

Comment: Yes you can have those. So that your core implementation where you would like all the users/implementers of your specification to use certain logic without changing that.

Comment: can a specification have classes? (concrete classes)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned earlier. Spec can have classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

A library contains declaration - Interface which fixes method. E.g.

```
public interface SaveInterface {
  void save();
}
```

You use the interface to save your data but implementation could be different. Tomcat saves the content here adn another application there. All depends on real implementation. But you in your logic don't care how it's implemented. You use the interface.

Comment: Then where is the code which implements these interfaces? For example in tomcat?

Comment: I only used the servlet-api.jar to compile my program. Therefore all what I need to run the program also is the same jar. why would I need any other code which implements these interfaces

Comment: To compile you need only interfaces. When yoou run your code (on tomcat) implementation for the interfaces is provided by tomcat.

Comment: what is  meant by "implementation for the interfaces"

Comment: class which implements the interface

Comment: why would I need classes which implements those interfaces (other than the servlets I have written)?